# QGIS Helmert transformation plugin?

Tags: python, qgis

I'm a VBA developer, but I'm looking for a QGIS plug to use the Helmert transformation to convert latitudes and longitudes to grid references, or equivalent mapping to the XY plane. The code for the Helmert transformation in VBA is given rather longwindedly in [this online resource from the UK Ordnance Survey](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/navigation-technology/os-net/coordinate-spreadsheet.html).  I have recently been asked to adapt [another Excel spreadsheet, published by the London Datastore](http://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/excel-mapping-template-for-london-boroughs-and-wards), which works by containing shape objects, which could be created by VBA code reading a set of XY coordinates, to use other public domain geographical boundary shape files.  I could do this by reading the shapefiles into QGIS, exporting them as KML, and then converting the lat lon KML numbers to XY coordinates using VBA, but I feel sure this step would be better done in Python as a QGIS plug in.

Am I right?
Is there such a plug in already in existence?
If not, anyone like to help make it happen, or is this how I get to grips with learning Python?

Comment: better to ask at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks - I might have found the Python code there I needed

Comment: @TimLund Could you please share your findings as this might help others with the same problem